# Rails - incrementing integers from db with concurrency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency

In our database, we have a table for `comments` and `blogs`.

There's a field `comments`.`comment_blog_index` that increments for each comment in the blog.

...so if we have 3 comments for a particular blog, the value for `comment_blog_index` for each comment is: `1`, `2`, `3` (respectively)

The code that sets `comment_blog_index` looks like this:

```
@comment = Comment.new
@comment.comment_blog_index = @blog.comments.count + 1
```

The problem happens when two users trigger this code simultaneously. It will calculate the same value for both users, and the `comment_blog_index` is duplicated.

I've seen code for `Item.increment_counter( :total_bids, item.id )`, but that requires you to already have a record in the database in a table that stores a summation. In our case, the record is being created inside the `commments`` table.

How do we prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already seen your current method is not safe. You could add validations and callbacks and all manner of things to try and make it safe but I would suggest that kind of work should happen at the database level.

Either [implement a propert auto-incrementing field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9534482/385532) or [offload that work to a gem](https://github.com/celsodantas/protokoll).

Answer (score -1):

It will help 
[Generate an auto increment field in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513739/generate-a-auto-increment-field-in-rails)
It shows how auto increment can be implemented in rails

Comment: Code examples are always welcome and better then just a link ;)

Comment: I appreciate your advice sir.