# Rails models - Saving attributes with SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to use sql during the construction of an ActiveRecord object?

For example,

```
@user = User.new
@user.name = params[:name]
@user.via_sql.id = `select count(1) from users`
@user.save
```

This is just a silly example, but I need to deal with a concurrency problem.

I'd like to be able to do this so I can still use ActiveRecord callbacks.

Comment: Please state the actual problem you're having, maybe there is a "Rails" way to solve it. That being said, there is a method called `find_by_sql`.

Comment: My actual problem is dealing with incrementing a value, while dealing with a concurrency issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086570/rails-incrementing-integers-from-db-with-concurrency/24086648#24086648 Thanks.