# Why does activerecord not populate an auto-incrementing column in the item returned from a create?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Why does rails not populate an auto-incrementing column in the item returned from a create? Is there a better way to do this?

In rails, when you do `a = Foo.create` then `a.id` is populated

But if you have a field that was created via

```
def up   
  execute "ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN my_auto_incrementing_column INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT not null UNIQUE KEY;"
end
```

Then that field does not appear when you use create. You have to use a reload also.

```
a = Foo.create
a.id # not nil
a.my_auto_incrementing_column # nil
a.reload
a.my_auto_incrementing_column # is now populated
```

Version information:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-darwin14.5.0]
$ bundle exec rails -v
Rails 3.2.12
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.26, for osx10.10 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Some background:

This code is being applied to a large existing in-production rails codebase that requires that all id fields be UUIDs. The auto_increment column is not a primary key, because it was added after we had discovered that a new external integration partner could not handle using our existing long unique identifiers (UUIDs).

We are working hard to update our version of ruby but we don't want to wait for that as a solution to this problem. Also, after reading changelogs in activerecord, I still don't have proof that any future version of ruby/rails will contain a bugfix for this problem.

The code which I want to improve:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :object_containing_auto_incrementing_column

  def my_method
    if self.object_containing_auto_incrementing_column.nil?
      self.object_containing_auto_incrementing_column = ObjectContainingAutoIncrementingColumn.create(owner: self)
      self.object_containing_auto_incrementing_column.reload
    end
    self.object_containing_auto_incrementing_column.my_auto_incrementing_column
  end
end
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/9534482/531479

Comment: @CWitty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513739/generate-an-auto-increment-field-in-rails/9534482#9534482 was very helpful in designing this solution, but it does not explain why rails has this bug or how to get around it. Also it is based on postgres, so some of the advice has syntax which does not apply.

Comment: Please find out what `SHOW CREATE TABLE` thinks the table looks like.  I want to see if activerecord correctly translated what your code said.

Comment: It sounds like your code is changing it on disk and not in memory and so the reload is required to fetch the data. mysql of course uses flush as well for modifications to tables.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload

Comment: This is a limitation of MySql itself. Take a look at the `mysql2` driver. It has a `last_id` method specifically for getting the id of the last insert. http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.4.2/Mysql2/Client#last_id-instance_method. There is no equivalent method for getting other fields. You have to do a select after the insert, which is what you are doing with `reload`. Postgres and oracle have a `RETURNING` statement for doing this, but it looks like that is not supported by `ActiveRecord`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.12/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L369) it does not appear that ActiveRecord tries to populate auto-incrementing columns. It only assigns the value that is returned by the `INSERT` statement to the `#id` attribute and nothing else.

```
 # ActiveRecord:: Persistence::ClassMethods
 def create
 # ...
   self.id ||= new_id if self.class.primary_key
 # ...
 end
```

If you want to populate `my_auto_incrementing_column` without hitting the DB twice, I think there is no way around patching ActiveRecord itself.

Have a look at how the [insert method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.12/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L80-L92) is implemented:

```
  # Returns the last auto-generated ID from the affected table.
  #
  # +id_value+ will be returned unless the value is nil, in
  # which case the database will attempt to calculate the last inserted
  # id and return that value.
  #
  # If the next id was calculated in advance (as in Oracle), it should be
  # passed in as +id_value+.
  def insert(arel, name = nil, pk = nil, id_value = nil, sequence_name = nil, binds = [])
    sql, binds = sql_for_insert(to_sql(arel, binds), pk, id_value, sequence_name, binds)
    value      = exec_insert(sql, name, binds)
    id_value || last_inserted_id(value)
  end
```

There might not be any trivial way to change the current API to populate your field in question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is still not possible to get in create() a field (not id) generated in autoincrement at database level by SEQUENCE.

I worked around the problem

in my case: **PostgreSQL AUTOINCREMENT by SEQUENCE**

with an **after_create** callback

*Migration*

```rb
class CreateFoo < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :foo do |t|
      t.integer :autoinc_field
    end
    execute "CREATE SEQUENCE table_name_seq OWNED BY table_name.autoinc_field INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 100000"
    execute "ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN autoinc_field SET DEFAULT nextval('table_name_seq');"
  end
end
```

*Model*

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :reload
end
```

*Result*

```bash
>> Foo.create!.autoinc_field 
=> 100000
```