# Active Record DB Modeling - Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok guys, this might be a little bit confusing so stick with me. Let me start by introducing my tables. Basically I created four tables upon migration.

- Students
- Teachers
- Subjects
- Admin User

Here are my migration files:

Students:

```
def up
    create_table :students, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer "student_id",:primary_key => true
      t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
      t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string "email", :default => ' ', :null => false
      t.string "birthday"
      t.string "subjects"
      t.string "teachers"
      t.string "username", :limit => 25
      t.string "password_digest"
      t.timestamps
    end
```

Teachers:

```
def up
    create_table :teachers, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer "teacher_id", :primary_key => true
      t.string "first_name"
      t.string "last_name"
      t.string "email", :default => ' ', :null => false
      t.string "birthday"
      t.string "subjects"
      t.string "username", :limit => 25
      t.string "password_digest"
      t.timestamps
    end
```

Subjects:

```
def up
  create_table :subjects, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer "subject_id", :primary_key => true
    t.string "subject_name"
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Admin Users:

```
def up
  create_table :admin_users, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer "admin_user_id", :primary_key => true
    t.string "username", :limit => 25
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

So now let me get through the explanation. Basically:

- one student can have many teachers
- one teacher can have many students
- one student can have many subjects
- one teacher can teach many subjects
- the admin can access all of this (create, edit, delete)

I created this fields and set them up on my models like this:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers
  has_many :admin_users
  has_secure_password
  self.primary_key = :student_id

end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
  has_many :admin_users
  has_secure_password

end

class Subject < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers
  has_many :admin_users

  # scope :search, lambda { |query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])}

end

class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord

  has_secure_password

  scope :newest_first, lambda { order("created_at ASC") }
  scope :oldest_first, lambda { order("created_at DESC") }
  # scope :search, lambda { |query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])}
end
```

Now I manually inserted data on mysql data record and then tried to pull up the records for student's subjects and teachers form fields.

How can I manage my database effectively esp teachers, students, and subjects??? Is there anything I need to do first to correlate the tables I have? Please help. Sorry for the long post. I am a newbie here. Appreciate your explanation (layman's term) and answers.

Check my models. Do I need to create a separate table to correlate teachers, students, and subjects?

Side Note: When I pull up my students and teachers field it gives me an error `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f9c504361d0` ERROR.

Comment: you have  `t.string "teachers"` in student table. What you expect `student.teachers` to return?

Comment: Hi Pardeep Dhingra, I edited my question sorry. Got confused.

Comment: Check my models. Do I need to create a separate table to correlate teachers, students, and subjects?

Comment: First remove that `teachers` string from student table and you need to study has_many through relations.

Comment: Can you point out one by one in the answer so that I can follow through?

Answer (score 1):

I think this relation should work in your case:

Students:

```
def up
  create_table :students, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer "student_id",:primary_key => true
    t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
    t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
    t.string "email", :default => ' ', :null => false
    t.string "birthday"
    t.string "subjects"
    t.string "username", :limit => 25
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Ref: [Generating auto increment with sequence 1001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513739/generate-an-auto-increment-field-in-rails) 
Teachers:

```
def up
    create_table :teachers, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer "teacher_id", :primary_key => true
      t.string "first_name"
      t.string "last_name"
      t.string "email", :default => ' ', :null => false
      t.string "birthday"
      t.string "subjects"
      t.string "username", :limit => 25
      t.string "password_digest"
      t.timestamps
    end
end
```

Subjects:

```
def up
  create_table :subjects, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer "subject_id", :primary_key => true
    t.string "subject_name"
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Enrolled Subjects:

```
def up
  create_table :enrolled_subjects, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer "subject_id"
    t.integer "teacher_id"
    t.integer "student_id"
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrolled_subjects
  has_many :subjects, through: :enrolled_subjects
  has_many :teachers, through: :enrolled_subjects    

  def teacher_names
    self.teachers.map(&:first_name).join(", ")
  end
end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :enrolled_subjects
  has_many :subjects, through: :enrolled_subjects
  has_many :students, through: :enrolled_subjects
end

class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrolled_subjects
  has_many :students, through: :enrolled_subjects
  has_many :teachers, through: :enrolled_subjects
end

class EnrolledSubject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student, foreign_key: :student_id
  belongs_to :subject, foreign_key: :subject_id
  belongs_to :teacher, foreign_key: :teacher_id
end
```

[Example Repository](https://github.com/railites/HasManyThroughExample)

Comment: Can you explain more? can you also site Pardeep and edit my migration what fields is supposed to be there? Do I need to create a new table with studend_id, teachers_id, and subjects_id on that?

Comment: Also when I manually insert data from mysql will it automatically populate the teachers and subjects field when students enrolled?

Comment: Don't add data manually through mysql. Try rails console to add data instead.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem until you are adding relation data to in `EnrolledSubject`. I haven't tested this relation, please give it a shot and let me know if it works for you. I will add more explanation

Comment: yeah on rails console.

Comment: last question. when I call this on my views. can it be like this? ***<%@students.each do |student|%>
    <tr>
     <td><%= student.student_id %></td> 
     <td><%= student.username %></td> 
    <td><%= student.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= student.last_name %></td> 
    <td><%= student.email %></td> 
    <td><%= student.birthday %></td> 
    <td><%= student.teachers %></td> 
    <td><%= student.subjects %></td> 


<% end %>***

Comment: Didn't get you. Like what?

Comment: Would that automaticall populate the data then?

Comment: `<%= student.teachers %>` and `<%= student.subjects %>` will be array of objects. You can't directly display it. you can create any helper method to help with that. like i am adding one in student model.

Comment: Is there a way I can display the contents in a formatted text form for teachers and students?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134201/discussion-between-jim-carter-and-pardeep-dhingra).

Comment: now you can use `<%= student.teachers_name %>` this will return you comma separated teachers name.

Comment: How about my admin user? am I going to just stick with my current migrations and models? (admin user is for the administrator)

Comment: We don't need to link `admin_users` with any table above. You can directly call All `students` and its related `subjects` and `teachers` as admin.

Comment: I see. probably that would be on the access part. for now its good to know if it can pull it up. one moment. trying this out.

Comment: BTW Pardeep do you know a way to make the auto increment value for all of my id to start on a specific number upon migration lets say the student id must start on the number 1001 and then incrementing...DO you know?

Comment: I only used this *** t.integer "teacher_id", :auto_increment => true, :primary_key => true*** but i am not sure if we can put :default => 1001

Comment: would that work on MYSQL? isnt that not for PostgreSQL?

Comment: I successfully migrated the files and tried to add a new record via rails console. **stud = Student.create(:student_id => 1, :first_name => 'Sam', :last_name => 'Norton', :email => 'samuelnico.norton@gmail.com', :birthday => '12/05/1990', :subjects => 'English', :username => 'samnorton05', :password => 'Grace0512')** BUT GOT THIS ERROR **ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :enrolled_subjects in model Student**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134307/discussion-between-pardeep-dhingra-and-jim-carter).